# Persistent cart session

Tags: session

Is **"persistent cart session"** in fact checkout/session or is it a separate session? If it is separate, can I use it from my modules? I need some data to persist together with the shopping cart content.

Comment: Beware - persistent cart does not work with compilation in EE 1.11 / CE 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **need data to persist** with the *shopping cart* session, **extend the shopping cart**. No need to piggyback on the customer persistence.

If you need data, you can extend the following tables - `sales_flat_quote`, `sales_flat_quote_item` to inject your domain-specific logic into the sales. The persistence module should resurrect the shopping cart session as per usual - only associating it to customers that have logged in / performed actions on different devices.

Persistance is also **limited** in CE. Wishlists and more aren't available in CE, only in EE. In CE 1.6 / EE 1.11 it was unable to work with compilation. I'm not sure if this was addressed in later releases.

Comment: I did extend sales_flat_quote and it works well. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it - awesome!